# How can use Ado. Net from Delphi Win32

Tags: delphi, ado.net, interop

Is possible to use [ADO .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28VS.71%29.aspx) from an Win32 Application build with Delphi 7.

maybe using [CrossTalk](http://www.atozed.com/CrossTalk/Blog/20090503.en.aspx) or [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx)?

Any recommendation is welcome.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell why do you need that? In most cases there is another way. Win32 and .NET are different and it is better not to mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience directly with using ADO.NET this way, but I believe [CrossTalk](http://www.atozed.com/CrossTalk/Blog/20090503.en.aspx) would be more suited to that than [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx).  I know you can use a [.NET Class via COM](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32754), which might work for you.  You might combine that with the article on [using ADO.NET DataSets](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28631) . . .

Answer (score 0):

You could also try managed VCL (http://www.managed-vcl.com/) or try to do the interop part with your own classes yourself